# ¿Cómo cambiar color según estado enable de un TextInputLayout? Android

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-layout, edittext

estoy usando

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

mi código es

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_holamundo"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="HOLA MUNDO">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tiet_holamundo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

y me aparece de este modo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si pongo el selector encima se ve de esta forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todo muy bien   ahora le agrego el enable false para que no se pueda editar.

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_holamundo"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="HOLA MUNDO">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tiet_holamundo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

y se ve exactamente igual.. de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi idea es identificar cuando este en enable y visualizar de otro color ( como si le estuviera dando un boxBackgroundColor)

por ejemplo de este modo.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_holamundo"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/solid_yellow"
                android:hint="HOLA MUNDO">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/tiet_holamundo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

y se vea así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PRUEBA 1**

creo un selector color /  text_input_layout_stroke_color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/solid_blue" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/solid_yellow" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/solid_green" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/solid_red"/>
</selector>
```

se lo añado a TextInputLayout

```
 app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
```

pero nunca detecta el **TextInputEditText** si esa en estado enable **false** . en mi caso siempre muestra de color rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PRUEBA 2**

creo un selector en drawable / txt_selec

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yellow" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

y lo agrego en el **TextInputEditText**

```
 android:background="@drawable/txt_selec"
```

y en efecto logro detectar el enable  y lo hace correcto.   pero se pierde por completo el diseño del TextInputLayout

```
enable = true
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
enbale = false
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para que tome el diseño correcto?**

Comment: ya te respondí esto en tu pregunta anterior, debes crear un colorStateList y definir los estados ahí. Además estás usando una versión muy vieja. La actual es 1.3.0

Comment: Primeramente actualiza la dependencia, es importante.

Comment: ok, hice lo que me comentaron. pero aun no logro hacerlo correctamente, añadí comentarios y ejemplo en mi pregunta.

Comment: el ejemplo que te dí funcionaba correctamente, lo probé. Pero lo que intentas hacer ahora es darle un color de fondo a un outlined text field, el cuál está diseñado para no tener fondo. Si usas el filled text field puedes darle cualquier color de fondo y automaticamente ajustará su transparencia dependiendo del estado. Todos los componentes de material desing están basados en [user research](https://medium.com/google-design/the-evolution-of-material-designs-text-fields-603688b3fe03), debes confiar en ellos

Comment: ya lo intente como tu me indicas.. si es el fondo o el contorno .. es completamente lo mismo.. no lo identifica. .. es como si no supiera que el TextInputEditText esta en enable.. podrías indicarme el cambio por acá. la  otro publicación  lo tuve que borrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al igual que en tu pregunta anterior, el error es que estás aplicando el enabled al TextInputEditText en vez de al TextInputLayout.

Igualmente te dejo un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable:

res/color/text_field.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#0F0" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#F00" />
    <item android:color="#00F" />
</selector>
```

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
    <style name="outlinedTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_field</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/text_field</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_field</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="focused">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="enabled"
        android:paddingVertical="16dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="enabled with text">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:text="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:hint="disabled"
        android:paddingVertical="16dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/outlinedTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:hint="disabled with text">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:text="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probado en un Pixel 3 API 30

### Ahora con el estilo outlined original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrás ver, los estados son claramente diferenciables. No hay necesidad de confundir al usuario con algo diferente.

Comment: Mi amigo. muchas gracias. mi error fueron en dos lados. 1. no actualizar a la ultima versión.  2. hacer el enable al TextInputEditText  en vez del TextInputLayout .. me ayudaste mucho. gracias por el tiempo. y como dices es mas que suficiente con los colores nativos ..